# Problems about Wiener algebra(absolutely convergent fourier series)

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, wiener-algebra

The Wiener algebra $A(\mathbb T)$ is defined as the space of all functions defined on $\mathbb T$(the torus) such that its fourier series satisfies: $$\|f_n\|_{A(\mathbb T)}:=\sum\limits_{n}|\hat f(n)|<\infty.$$

An immediate consequence is stated: **let $f_n\in A(\mathbb T)$ and $\|f_n\|\leq 1.$ Assume that $f_n$ converge to $f$ uniformly on $\mathbb T$. Then $f\in A(\mathbb T)$ and $\|f\|\leq 1.$**

Here is my proof which can be skipped for readers who are not interested in:

**Proof:**
   Since $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, then for any $m>0$, there exists $N_m$ such that if $n\geq N_m$, $$\sup_t|f(t)-f_n(t)|<\frac{1}{m}.$$
For any $m\in\mathbb Z, n\geq N_m$, $$|\hat f(k)-\hat f_n(k)|=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb T}|f(t)-f_{n}(t)|e^{-ikt}dt\leq\frac{C}{mk},$$
for any $k\in\mathbb Z.$

Thus it is obvious that for $n\geq N_m$, there holds
$$\sum\limits_{|k|\leq m}|\hat f|=\sum\limits_{|k|\leq m}(|\hat f(k)-\hat f_n(k)|+|\hat f_n(k)|)\leq 2\sum\limits_{j=1}^m\frac{1}{mj}+1\leq 2\frac{\log m}{m}+1.$$
As $m\rightarrow \infty,\ \|f\|_{A(\mathbb T)}\leq 1.$

Q.E.D

Is there any problems in it? I can't find any errors in it.

My central problem is described as follows:

**Problem: the conditions do not imply $\lim\|f-f_n\|_{A(\mathbb T)}=0$, i believe this conclusion is correct, however, i cannot find some counterexamples. Can someone tell me the counterexample**: my idea is to construct $$
\widehat{f_n}(m)=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&\frac{\mathrm{sgn}(m)}{n}& m\in[-n,n]\backslash\{0\}\\
&0            & else.
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$However, i can not find it uniformly converges to $0.$

This problem follows from Yitzhak Katznelson "An introduction to harmonic analysis."

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
To start with, this is false:

’’For any $m\in\mathbb Z, n\geq N_m$,
$$|\hat f(k)-\hat f_n(k)|=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb T}|f(t)-f_{n}(t)|e^{-ikt}dt..’’$$

However, for any $k$ we have
$$|\hat f(k)-\hat f_n(k)|=
\left| \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb T}(f(t)-f_{n}(t))e^{-ikt}dt\right|\leq\|f-f_n\|_\infty\to0$$

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo, it's not an equality, what i am more interested in is the counterexample, can you offer me some inspiring hints？